# JSON Response into an HTML Table

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I want to display this info from a HTTPS GET request, into an info.

What I want to display:

```
[{"id":"833",
  "vps_id":"1924",
  "event":"Your new virtual cloud server has been deployed",
  "timestamp":"2015-05-03 07:52:55","IP":"176.42.87.106"},
 {"id":"834",
  "vps_id":"1924",
  "event":"Power Cycle",
  "timestamp":"2015-05-03 07:53:30","IP":"176.31.67.189"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly a cool jquery way to do this in like 2 lines, but sometimes a straighforward way is easier to understand:

```
$.http({
  url: myCoolURL,
  method: "GET"
}).then(function (result) {

  var tableHTML = "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>vps id</th><th>event</th></tr>";  

  $.each(result.data, function() {
    tableHTML += "<tr>";
    tableHTML += "<td>"+this.id+"</td>";
    tableHTML += "<td>"+this.vps_id+"</td>";
    tableHTML += "<td>"+this.event+"</td>";
    tableHTML += "</tr>";
  });

  tableHTML += "</table>";
  $("#tablediv").innerHTML = tableHTML;
});
```

Comment: @DanWilliams I edited to add the http thing.. there are several ways to do a httpget, so yours might be a bit different.  But basically my original answer should be in the response area of your GET.

Comment: @DanWilliams Try searching for basic jquery ajax example.  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first is a non-jquery example (so my $.each won't work unless you add jquery)

Comment: Ok. In 5 hours i will be able to use skype. If you want to talk now just add me in hangouts / gtalk

Comment: @DanWilliams sorry, skype isn't going to happen..  I think all of the pieces are there between the link and code above, you can do this!

Comment: This is what I have in my page:

Comment: <html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.http({
  url: "Website is here but it's a private API link",
  method: "GET"
}).then(function (result) {

  var tableHTML = "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>vps id</th><th>event</th></tr>";  

  $.each(result.data, function() {
    tableHTML += "<tr>";
    tableHTML += "<td>"+this.id+"</td>";
    tableHTML += "<td>"+this.vps_id+"</td>";
    tableHTML += "<td>"+this.event+"</td>";
    tableHTML += "</tr>";
  });

  tableHTML += "</table>";
  $("#tablediv").innerHTML = tableHTML;
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "result" var store a string like this: '[{"id":"833","vps_id":"1924","event":"Your new virtual cloud server has been deployed","timestamp":"2015-05-03 07:52:55","IP":"176.42.87.106"},{"id":"834","vps_id":"1924","event":"Power Cycle","timestamp":"2015-05-03 07:53:30","IP":"176.31.67.189"}]'

If i'm right, the result is:

Try this:

```
<div id="divTable"></div>


<script> 
     $.http({ url: "Website is here but it's a private API link", method: "GET" })
     .then(function (result) { 

         var tableHTML = "<table border='1'><tr><th>id</th><th>vps id</th><th>event</th></tr>"; 

         var json = eval(result);

         var itemsCount = Object.keys(json[0]).length;

         for(x = 0; x < json.length; x++)
         {
             tableHTML += "<tr>";

             var counter = 0;

             for(var key in json[x])
             {
                 if(counter < 3)
                      tableHTML += "<td>" + json[x][key] + "</td>";

                 counter++;
             }


             tableHTML += "</tr>";
        }

        tableHTML += "</table>";

        $("#divTable").html(tableHTML);

</script>
```

See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mjb4t5z1/2/

Comment: But It comes from a website like where do I put the link?

Comment: Here i can't use skype. But i have hangouts marciogonzalez85@gmail.com

Comment: @DanWilliams i hust updated the code above. Try it again

Comment: Hey @DanWilliams i updated the code above one more time. And jsfiddle too. Read the text above the code block.